# Passport-Facebook authentication is not providing email for all Facebook accounts

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am using [Passport-Facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) authentication.

```
  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
            clientID: 'CLIENT_ID',
            clientSecret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
            callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback"
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {            
            process.nextTick(function () {                
               console.log(profile)
            });               
        }
    ));
```

For some of the Facebook accounts I don't get the email_id and I even tried by using a scope variable such as below, but still I am unable to get the email_id.

> > profileUrl : " "  and ProfileFields : ['','']

Comment: Not every FB account _has_ an email address set … (People are able to sign up for FB using their mobile number as well.)

Comment: but i am not getting email from accounts which have email and to get registered to fb we need to have email id right??

Comment: I don’t see you ask for `email` permission anywhere … you said you tried to use scope, but where? And no, people do not have to give an email address to register for FB, as I already said.

Comment: Make sure to log `accessToken` there and try it with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). Make sure that the "email" permission on the left is *not greyed out*. If it is, you're not asking for the scope at the right time. See [this comment](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/214#issuecomment-348684429) on the passport-facebook project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775198/facebook-api-this-app-is-in-development-mode This solves my issue. Try this.

Answer (score 136):

Make sure these two things are in your code:

```
  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
            clientID: 'CLIENT_ID',
            clientSecret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
            callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback"
            passReqToCallback : true,
            profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'name'] //This
        },
```

and this:

```
app.get('/connect/facebook', passport.authorize('facebook', { scope : ['email'] }));
```

This gives you access to the following:

- profile.id
- profile.name.givenName
- profile.name.familyName
- profile.emails

The last one being an array, so use `profile.emails[0].value` to get the first email address of the user.

As `shamim reza` pointed out, you might want to check if `profile.emails !== undefined` because the property only exists if the user has at least one verified email address.

As `Weft` pointed out, you might have to use the property `email` instead of `emails`.

Comment: The meanjs boiler plate is missing the profileFields line

Comment: whoa, you saved my day. everyone talking about scope but no one about profileFields

Comment: give him "best answer" :)

Comment: One really need the 'profileFields' field. Besides, I didn't need the passReqToCallback. I searched in passport-facebook for that and it is not there (I guess it is not used, so you might leave it out).

Comment: what if the user didnt verified his email on facebook?

Comment: @ArslArsl if login user email is not verified, then facebook does not send email fields

Comment: Fails for me if I use "emails" in the `profileFields` array. Works if I use "email" instead.

Answer (score 26):

When you are authenticating use something similar to this. You need to use add 'email' in the scope when you authenticate.

```
app.get('/auth/facebook',
passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email']}),
    function(req, res){
});
```

That has worked for me.

Here were a few links that helped me out.

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/11
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook#how-do-i-ask-a-user-for-additional-permissions

Comment: Make sure to include the 'profileFields' field when setting up your strategy. Only adding 'scope' in here won't do the trick (at least didn't for me). For more info, look the other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32370813/1814970.

Comment: I am getting emails for some users but not for some users ? Any reasons for that ?

Comment: @SandipSubedi it seems like that question is answered by vinesh below

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add more information here.

While adding `profileFields: ['emails']` while creating FacebookStrategy and `passport.authorize('facebook', { scope : ['email'] })` solves issue for most of the users.

There are other possible reasons where you will not get  user's email after authentication.

- No e-mail address on account
- No confirmed e-mail address on account
- No verified e-mail address on account
- User entered a security checkpoint which required them to reconfirm
  their e-mail address and they have not yet done so
- User's e-mail address is unreachable

​
you need to make sure that your user does not have any of the issues listed above. more information can be found https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1802930019968631/

Answer (score 3):

When passport doesn't return the `profile.emails, profile.name.givenName, profile.name.familyName` fields, or if they are missing, you can try to parse the `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/` url, although you still need a token. You access the url, with of course a valid token, like:

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=

It outputs a JSON response like:

```
{
   "id": "5623154876271033",
   "name": "Kurt Van den Branden",
   "email": "kurt.vdb\u0040example.com",
   "first_name": "Kurt",
   "last_name": "Van den Branden"
}
```

Install the request module (`$ npm install request --save`), to be able to parse a JSON url and in your passport.js file:

```
const request = require("request");

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID        : 'CLIENT_ID',
        clientSecret    : 'CLIENT_SECRET',
        callbackURL     : "https://example.com/auth/facebook/callback"
    },
    function(req, token, profile, done) {

        let url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me?" +
                  "fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=" + token;

        request({
            url: url,
            json: true
        }, function (err, response, body) {
              let email = body.email;  // body.email contains your email
              console.log(body); 
        });
    }
));
```

You can add a lot of other parameters to the url, although some of them require user permission to return values. You can play with it on: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're providing the scope parameter into the first .authenticate() call, not the callback.

Like this:

```
router.get("/auth/facebook", passport.authenticate("facebook", {
    scope: [ "email" ], // scope goes here, not below
}));

router.get("/auth/facebook/callback",
    passport.authenticate("facebook", {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/login",
    }),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [code provided as an example in the `passport-facebook` site](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example) as a starting point. Then, to get access to email, make sure to check [@Forivin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32370813/1814970).

Answer (score -3):

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: 'CLIENT_ID',
        clientSecret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
        callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback"
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {            
        process.nextTick(function () {                
           console.log(profile)
        });               
    }
));
```