# Passport-Facebook not providing email even if it is in scope

Tags: node.js, facebook, oauth, passport.js, facebook-oauth

In my application i register the facebook-strategie as follows:
But the returned profile does not contain the email-field....

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        // No email in the following colsole.log
        console.log(JSON.stringify(profile));
    }));
```

The get is as follows:

```
app.get('/oauth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    scope:['email']
}));
```

(So i am using scope as said here: [Passport-facebook doesn't get email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832763/passport-facebook-dont-get-email))

On the FB-Login Page iam even asked for the email and i do provide it:
[image]

Any help is very appriciated!

Comment: You need to ask for the email field also

Comment: How do i do this? I Thought i do this with `scope:['email']`

Comment: scope:['email'] is which permissions you want. When you call /me you need to do /me?fields=email

Answer (score 70, accepted):

From Facebook graph APIv2.4, we need to explicitly specify fields to get.

[Introducing Graph API v2.4](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/07/08/graph-api-v2.4/)

So, we can write like:

```
  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
      clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
      clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,
      profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'gender', 'link', 'locale', 'name', 'timezone', 'updated_time', 'verified'],
    },
```

Comment: I'm surprised this is not mentioned in official passport.js docs.

Answer (score 2):

You do have the callback part of the code, right?:

```
app.get('/oauth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    successRedirect: '/',
    scope:['email']
}));
```

And, yes, indeed, this should be done with the `scope:['email']`, as per instructions from your link and this one [here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880876/passport-facebook-authentication-is-not-providing-email-for-all-fbaccounts).

Comment: Yes, i also do have the email on the callback... This is strange

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the scope: "email".
Refer the below code.

Facebook authentication route:

```
// auth facebook
router.get("/auth/facebook", passport.authenticate("facebook", {
  scope: "email"
}));
```

and while configuring the FacebookStrategy, you need to also specify the profileFields.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/facebook/redirect",
  clientID: keys.facebook.clientID,
  clientSecret: keys.facebook.clientSecret,
  profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email', 'gender', 'name']
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
   // logic 
}))
```