# I can't get the email scope from facebook login on my website to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, email, passport.js

I used [this code](https://github.com/BrentAureli/Youtube-Tutorials/tree/master/NodeJS%20Tutorials/Tutorial%2010%20-%20Facebook%20OAuth). I filled out everything, ID, Secret, callback url, and local database.

I set the urls on my facebook app to "http://localhost:3000/" and for the url of the website I tried both "http://localhost:3000/" and "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"

Also I changed the port on the app from 8080 to 3000 to match it.

Whenever I clicked the login, the server would crash, telling me there was an uncaught error somewhere in a node module of mongoose and that it couldn't "read property 0 of undefined", so I figured that would happen if there was no permission to access the email scope (since it does newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;), so I tried to comment out that line.

After commenting out that line, the server wouldn't crash anymore when doing the login, and when I was redirected to the profile page, I got the token, ID, and displayName.

So, the login works if I don't request the email, but when I add that line of code to request the email, it crashes.

I'm requesting the "email" scope like this:

> app.get("/auth/facebook", passport.authenticate("facebook", {scope: ["email"]}));

I searched previous questions, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

`read property 0 of undefined` for `profile.emails[0].value` means that `profile` does not have a property called `emails`.

I'm assuming, since it is a single profile, it is `email` and not `emails`. Furthermore, it could be a single email, and not an array of emails.

You can print the `profile` object and check what properties it has. Then use the right property that you need.

Comment: OK, I tried that, and this is what is in "profile":

id: the id
username: undefined
displayName: the name
name: an object with familyName, middleName and givenName, all undefined.
gender: undefined
profileUrl: undefined
provider: facebook
_raw and _json: objects with displayName and id.

So, I'm not getting any email at all. I guess it's because I'm not requesting the email scope correctly? How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm just shooting in the dark here. The facebook user you are trying to access needs to have given access permissions for your app.

Comment: I'm accessing with my fb account, and I tried already checking the permissions (it says the app can see the email), I tried removing and re-accepting the permissions, and using a different account, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

I found it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31554393/4045784)

Quoting:

> From Facebook graph APIv2.4, we need to explicitly specify fields to
>   get.
>
> Introducing Graph API v2.4
>
> So, we can write like:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
  clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,
  profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'gender', 'link', 'locale', 'name', 'timezone', 'updated_time', 'verified'],
},
```

For some reason this is not in the passport.js documentation I read.