# Passport-facebook doesn't get email

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, express, passport-facebook

I have already implemented the Facebook-LogIn in my website with express js and passport-Facebook. It works well (I get field profile), but the problem is that I don't get the Email. I get an error:

```
email   : profile.emails[0].value,
```

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

My code:

```
passport.use('facebook',new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID            : config.facebook.id,
        clientSecret    : config.facebook.secret,
        callbackURL  : '/auth/facebook/callback',
        profileFields : ['id', 'displayName', 'emails','photos']
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        User.findOne({provider_id: profile.id}, function(err, user) {
            if(err) throw(err);
            if(!err && user!= null) return done(null, user);

            var user = new User({
                provider_id : profile.id,
                name                 : profile.displayName,
                email               : profile.emails[0].value,
                photo               : profile.photos[0].value,
            });
            user.save(function(err) {
                if(err) throw err;
                return done(null, user);
            });
        });
    }));
```

It would be great if someone could help me with the solution to my problem :)

Comment: have you tried logging the profile object to see what it contains?

Comment: i tried it now. Profile contains no emails...

Comment: what happens if you don't use profileFields parameter?

Comment: i have more information. but no email

Comment: maybe the user's email hasn't been verified?

Comment: maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880876/passport-facebook-authentication-is-not-providing-email-for-all-fbaccounts) will help

Comment: perfect, adding 'scope' work, sorry but I could not find any answers. thank you very much

Comment: Please upvote the answer in the other question if it helped you. We can then merge both questions as they seem to be duplicates.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Facebook login works for all of our testers apart from one. For some reason, one profile does not return an email. Going to the users profile on Facebook shows that they have two emails registered: a facebook.com one and a gmail.com one, but they are not returned when trying to log in with PassportJS. Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem. We had 10 test users, all 10 had email addresses associated with their Facebook account. But for one of the 10 testers, Facebook did not return the 'email' JSON property in the profile response. I have no idea why, since it looked identical to other Facebook profiles that worked fine.

The fix was to change this line:

```
passport.authenticate('facebook')
```

To this:

```
passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: [ 'email' ] })
```

I still can't explain why it worked for 9/10, but not for one. Either way, it's fixed now :-)

Comment: Same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880876/passport-facebook-authentication-is-not-providing-email-for-all-fbaccounts

Comment: Had same problem this helped:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291357/passport-facebook-cant-get-about-me-and-email-profile-fields

Comment: Ask that one tester to remove this app from his Facebook account. and then try again. it will work

Answer (score 1):

Try this `passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: [ 'email' ] })`

Also add a new field `profileFields: [ 'email' , 'name' ]` in the facebookStrategy

Comment: please write more neat answer that is understood by community.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion. As I am a new to stackoverflow, I am not familiar to the way of answering. Next time I will try my best.

Answer (score 0):

```
  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,
    passReqToCallback:true
  },
```

Comment: a short explanation of the answer would be useful to the OP