# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined passport-facebook

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, express, passport-facebook

Whenever I try to login using facebook, it will return this error, i have followed this link advise but still no luck. [Passport-facebook doesn't get email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832763/passport-facebook-dont-get-email)

```
newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Here's the code

```
var passport = require('passport');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');

var facebookConfig = {
  clientID: 'ID',
  clientSecret: 'SECRET',
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/facebook/callback'
};

var facebookInit = function(token, refreshToken, profile, callback) {
  User.findOne({ "facebook.id": profile.id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    if (user) {
      return callback(null, user);
    }

    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
    newUser.facebook.token = token;
    newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;
    newUser.facebook.displayName = profile.displayName;
    newUser.facebook.photo = profile.photos[0].value

    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      return callback(null, newUser);
    });
  });
}

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(facebookConfig, facebookInit));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, callback) {
  callback(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, callback) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    callback(err, user);
  });
});

module.exports = {
  facebookLogin: passport.authenticate("facebook",  { scope: ['email'] }),
  facebookCallback: passport.authenticate("facebook", {
    successRedirect: "/profile",
    failureRedirect: "/"
  })
}
```

I tried to change the scope from `{ scope: 'email' }` to `{ scope: ['email'] }`, still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try explicitly specify email field in your config? In your case it should be:

```
var facebookConfig = {
  clientID: 'ID',
  clientSecret: 'SECRET',
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/facebook/callback',
  profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'gender']
};
```

Pay attention to **profileFields**, seems like it's required by APIv2.4.
That should help.