# Can't get email information from Facebook passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

currently I am working on a project to store information from Facebook Authentication, I already checked [Passport-facebook doesn't get email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832763/passport-facebook-doesnt-get-email) to see the solution, and here is my code

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(
  {
    clientID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    callbackURL: 'http://1bc600b4.ngrok.io/auth/facebook/callback',
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'name', 'photos', 'email'],
  },
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log(profile);
    models.User.findOne({ where: { facebookID: profile.id } }).then((existinguser) => {
      if (existinguser) {
        // Nothing will happen, the ID already exists
        done(null, existinguser);
      } else {
        models.User.create({
          // email: profile.emails[0].value,
          username: 'hello',
          firstname: profile.name.givenName,
          lastname: profile.name.familyName,
          facebookID: profile.id,
          avatar: `https://graph.facebook.com/${profile.id}/picture?redirect=true&height=470&width=470`,
          avatarThumb: profile.photos[0].value,
          last_login: Date.now(), }).then(user => done(null, user));
      }
    });
  },
));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.get('/flogin', passport.authenticate(
  'facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }),
));

app.get(
  '/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.send('AUTH WAS GOOD!');
  },
);
```

I don't understand why I use this way and the email information still not show up, which makes me lose a lot of information, can anyone give me a hint on solving this prob? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has been there for a while, you need to include email scope and even then it might not send facebook email because of user privacy settings or if the user's email is not verified at the facebook's end.

You could add scope like this:

```
passport.use(
   new FacebookStrategy({
            clientID: 'CLIENT_ID',
            clientSecret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
            callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback"
            passReqToCallback : true,
            profileFields: ['emails'] // email should be in the scope.
   })
)
```

Also you would need to add this to your authorize route as well,

```
app.get('/login/facebook', passport.authorize('facebook', { scope : ['email'] }));
```

If the emails return, It will be an list of it and you could access them like this:

```
1. profile.emails // [email1@example.com, somerandomdude@gmail.com]
2. profile.emails[1].value // randomdude@yahoo.com
```

If it doesn't return, you can use their username or id and create a facebook email atleast temporarily like this:

```
username@facebook.com // this exists.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I tried several times and found these codes work for me, and I found that I need to not add passReqToCallback into my code, otherwise it would keep showing the done is not a function

Comment: Great, Glad to know it fixed your issue!

Comment: You are the best!